# Где скачать support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

Нужно скачать support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1 и support:support-v4:21.1.2. Никак не могу найти их. Студия предлагает скачать только 23+. Ткните носом, что я не так делаю?

Comment: А зачем вам устаревшая версия библиотеки?

Comment: есть подозрение. что v-4 и v-7 должны быть одинаково либо ревизии 21 либо ревизии 22. В build.gradle укажите в зависимостях что вы хотите скачать. но в таком случае у вас несколько параметров должны быть синхронизированы: compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, targetSdkVersion и версии appcompat-библиотек

Comment: @ЮрийСПб чтобы работала последняя "новая" версия 23+ нужно обновлять студию, а обновленная студия содержит интерфейс сильно отличный от предыдущих. Я только изучаю программирование на андроид и все уроки по старым версиям.

Comment: @AlexZiko моя опечатка, меня интересует, где скачать версию 21.1.2.
в Билде указал:
compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

   minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.1.2'
Но при синхроне, студия ругается, что нет вышеперечисленных библиотек. Логично предположить, что их надо скачать, правильно?

Comment: а почему именно 21,1,2?

Comment: Не правильно. Она сама все скачает. Добавьте в вопрос build.gradle целиком.

Comment: я исправил на compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3' и у меня все сбилдилось

Comment: вот список ревизий https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо вручную в `build.gradle` указать нужные вам версии библиотек. При этом вам надо:

1. Загрузить через `SDKManager` `Android Support Repository`
2. Загрузить `API` нужных вам версий там же.
3. Проследить, чтобы версии `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` совпадали с версией нужных вам библиотек поддержки.
4. Смириться с тем, что студия будет подчёркивать все эти строки и настаивать на их обновлении.

А лучше всего не страдать фигнёй и пользовать предлагаемые студией **последние версии** всех библиотек и прочих инструментов, для избежания встречи со всякими багами, кои есть в старых версиях и кои исправлены в новых. Ведь в случае сталкивания с оными вам ничто не поможет кроме обновления всех компонентов до последних версий.

Comment: всё так и делаю.
1. через СДКМенеджер установлены, но там установлена версия Android Support Repository 23.0.0(может в этом проблема? как скачать старую версию?)
2. Android 5.0.1 (API 21) все пункты в этом разделе скачены
3. Всё отметил
4. Подчеркивания не важны)
Как с Вами можно связаться напрямую?

Comment: Пункты 1 и 3(в случае даунгрейда)  не обязательны. Да и 2 тоже.

Comment: @DenisMolodec, связываться напрямую нету смысла. Чтобы проверить работоспособность моего варианта - надо как следует поизвращаться. Возможно, надо и другие API скачать... В любом случае вам не стоит этим заниматься. Вам надо пользовать последние версии, а то что вы хотите сделать - пустая трата времени. Это вам тут (и не только тут) все скажут.

Comment: @DenisMolodec, то, что примеры по старым версиям не должно вас волновать. В 95% случаев это ни на что не влияет.

Comment: @pavlofff, я почти наобум написал. Мне сложно представить зачем вообще можно этим всерьёз заниматься)

Answer (score 3):

*support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1* не существует и ее нигде не скачать.

[Выпущенные ревизии](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions) библиотек поддержки Google.

Для существующей ревизии библиотеки достаточно в секции `dependences` указать ее версию в файле `build.gradle` приложения:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
```

Здесь будет подключена библиотека версии 22.1.0

Или

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.*'
```

Последняя доступная из ревизии 22